# Opening a file in append mode but truncating the file

Tags: c++, fstream, flags

I would like to open a file in `append` mode, but, if the file already exists, override its contents.

I have tried something like this, but this won't work (I don't have much experience with | and & operators, as you can notice):

```
 //does nothing
_fs.open(_path, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::trunc);
```

Then I decided to open the file in `out` mode and then close it before opening it again but in `append` mode, but of course this seems a bad programming way to do it:

```
if(fexists(_path.c_str())){//Checks if the file exists
    _fs.open(_path, std::ios::out);//Overrides the contents
    _fs.close();
}

_fs.open(_path, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
```

Then intuitively I wrote something like this:

```
_fs.open(_path, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app & std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
```

and now it's working, why?

Comment: why would you want to append a file if you are just going to delete it anyway, that is the point of truncate mode.  Also, you cannot open a file in BOTH `std::ios::app` and `std::ios::trunc` mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because

```
std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app & std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc
```

==

```
std::ios_base::out | (std::ios_base::app & std::ios_base::out) | std::ios_base::trunc
```

==

```
std::ios_base::out | 0 | std::ios_base::trunc
```

==

```
std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc
```

which is actually what you want: open file for writing and truncate it if it exists.

(And of course `std::ios_base::trunc` is redundant, as mentioned by [0x499602d2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2) - you could specify just `std::ios_base::out`)

Comment: Why is it equal to std::ios_base::trunc?

Comment: @usar `out | sapp & out | trunc` == `out | (sapp & out) | trunc` == `out | 0 | trunc` == `out | trunc`

Comment: it works also if I use: `_fs.open(_path, (std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc) & (std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app));`

Comment: @usar because it's again equal to `std::ios_base::out` :)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to open a file in append mode, but, if the file already exists, override its contents.

This is the same as simply emptying the file it whether or not it exists. `std::ofstream()` creates a new empty file when one doesn't exist, and if one does exists, by default its contents are erased unless you use `std::ios_base::app`.

So it sounds like you just want to open the file with only `std::ios_base::out`.

Comment: @usar When you open an output file with `out` (which is the default btw) it erases the contents of the file. Not unless you use `app` to append.